# SublimeLinter doesn't highlight properly

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter, eslint

SublimeLinter doesn't highlight properly. I tried to lint from console and ESLint's output is correct. I also tried to reinstall plugins(SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint) but it didn't help.

Here is example:

```
//Wrong highlight
var u[nused];
if (true) {
  var a[notherUnused];
}

//Correct highlight
var [unused];
if (true) {
  var [anotherUnused];
}

//ESLint output
1:5  error  unused is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
4:7  error  anotherUnused is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

[image: Link to screenshoot]

Comment: It was a problem with ESLint installed locally. Now I installed ESLint globally and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I installed ESLint globally and it works. Then I install it locally and remove previously installed globally. And it works. Magic...